# How to configure Kerberos authentication on the browsers which are on CITRIX page?

Tags: kerberos, citrix, hadoop, resource-management

We are connecting to our secure client network via CITRIX. We are using chrome to open all quick links. like ambari etc. They open and we are good there, but other useful links like RM and HISTORY server links, do not open as it needs kerberos authentication on the browser.

The url does not open due to unavailability of Kerberos ticket.

How do I enable the browsers on Citrix page to incorporate Kerberos authentication? I tried few things and attaching screenshots for the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgdCS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E21Vs.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZhZW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between Citrix and local machine sessions regarding kerberos browser authentication.

Your question

> How do I enable the browsers on Citrix page to incorporate Kerberos
>   authentication?

Could be rewritten as

> How do I enable the browsers to incorporate Kerberos authentication?

The error *Credentials cache permissions incorrect* looks to be a kerberos client issue, not a browser config issue.

- Check credentials file %TEMPDIR%/krb5cc_* permissions
- If you are using a third party kerberos client as [MIT Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/), check *default_ccache_name* parameter in kerberos config file.